# I can access my flutter from home but cannot access from another path on Catalina OS

Tags: flutter, dart, config, macos-catalina

I can access my flutter from home but cannot access from another path on Catalina OS

here my screen shoot

[image: Images]

and here the code

```
macbookpro@Cong-Fandi ~ % pwd  
/Users/macbookpro  
macbookpro@Cong-Fandi ~ % flutter --version  
Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 68587a0916 (7 weeks ago) • 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
Engine • revision b863200c37
Tools • Dart 2.5.0
macbookpro@Cong-Fandi ~ %  
macbookpro@Cong-Fandi ~ % cd Desktop    
macbookpro@Cong-Fandi Desktop % pwd 
/Users/macbookpro/Desktop  
macbookpro@Cong-Fandi Desktop % flutter --version  
zsh: command not found: flutter  
macbookpro@Cong-Fandi Desktop %
```

Comment: Please provide a path to flutter directory and I try to help

Answer (score 0):

After update to Catalina, I passed to zsh from bash. I added .zshrc file to home and export paths in it. but I saw this error in IntelliJ. 
I don’t know it’s why but I fixed it when I changed path to full directory. I mean before my path was like;
 ~/development/flutter/bin

I replaced it with;
 /Users/myusername/development/flutter/bin

If someone know it’s why, please comment it.